# Disable webpage caching for browser forward/back buttons

Tags: html, internet-explorer, jsf, cross-browser

I am using following meta tags to prevent browser caching for page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-stale=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />
<meta http-equiv="Vary" content="*" />
```

Case:

1. Browser is already opened with `page1`.
2. New link is pasted in the browser address bar and now secured page `page2` is opened.
3. User performs action on `page2` and is redirected to `page3`.

When clicking back button on `page3`, then user gets redirected to `page1` (no caching and works fine in this case). When user clicks forward button on `page1`, then the user is forwarded to the secured page `page2`. This shouldn't happen.

All of above is tested on IE9.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Can the down voters please correct me if i am wrong in something and not just down vote ?

Comment: always use a web filter to prevent browser to cache your pages see this for the code of web filter  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19018130/redirect-to-login-page-when-user-clicks-on-back-button-after-logout-in-jsf/19034603#19034603

Comment: + upvote for unjustified downvote

Comment: @hanan Ahmed, what exactly this filter does ?

Comment: A quick note: it seems not necessary to use both `post-check=0, pre-check=0`. It might even cause unexpected behavior on some browsers! See more information here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/07/20/using-post_2d00_check-and-pre_2d00_check-cache-directives.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the best solution is the following filter:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.faces.application.ResourceHandler;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet Filter implementation class NoCacheFilter
 */
  @WebFilter(urlPatterns = {"*.xhtml"})
  public class NoCacheFilter implements Filter {

/**
 * Default constructor. 
 */
public NoCacheFilter() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see Filter#destroy()
 */
public void destroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

/**
 * @see Filter#doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain)
 */

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    // apply no caching for all web pages except resources, you can customize that to be applied for specific pages
    if (!req.getRequestURI().startsWith(req.getContextPath() + ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER)) { // Skip JSF resources (CSS/JS/Images/etc)
        res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
        res.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
        res.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
    }

    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
/**
 * @see Filter#init(FilterConfig)
 */
public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

}
```

according to the answer in this question:

[Redirect to login page when user clicks on back button after logout in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19018130/redirect-to-login-page-when-user-clicks-on-back-button-after-logout-in-jsf/19034603#19034603)

Answer (score 7):

Your initial attempt with HTML `<meta http-equiv>` tags specifies the [right header values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers/2068407#2068407), however, this doesn't work at all because your pages are **already** served over HTTP. The `<meta http-equiv>` headers specifies "HTTP-equivalent" headers which are only used when the pages are **not** served using the HTTP protocol.

For example, when the pages are opened from local disk file system like as if you were doubleclicking a `.html` file in local disk file system explorer. This would open the `.html` file via `file://` URI instead of `http://` URI.

You should be setting those headers on the **real** HTTP response. You can investigate the headers of the current HTTP response by pressing F12 in Chrome/FireFox>=23/IE>=9 and exploring the HTTP traffic in *Network* tab. In case of specifically IE9/10, click the *Start capturing* button, reload the page, select the HTML page, click *Go to detailed view* button and finally click the *Response headers* tab. Here's a screenshot of how it look like in IE10 on your current question:

[image]

The right way to get those headers to end up there is using [`HttpServletResponse#setHeader()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#setHeader%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and friends like `setDateHeader()`, `addHeader()`, etc. As you figured, one way is a servlet filter.

#### See also:

- [Avoid back button on JSF web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305718/avoid-back-button-on-jsf-web-application/10305799#10305799)